# T4 LCR user manual

Tags: transistors

Is there a detailed user manual out there for the T4 LCR?
Or else, is there supposed to be a proper way to measure transistors?

I noticed when I turn in a TIP122 transistor the other way around a NPN transistor becomes a PNP!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is probably normal behavior because TIP122 is a Darlington BJT witch internal resistors and protection diode.  https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP120-D.PDF

Comment: Something is definitely wrong. hFe should be >2,000. Consider the possibility that this darlington is damaged! Can you try any others, or perhaps set up the darlington on a breadboard and with your multimeter verify that the beta gain is way off for what it should be?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/lorf/transistortester/blob/config/T4-Li-Ion/Doku/trunk/pdftex/english/ttester.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's it. the GM328 is an open-source LCR, but it's different than the LCR-T4. However, I am thinking about flashing the GM328 onto my LCR-T4 since they both use the Atmega328.

Comment: That is the LCR-T4 user manual, I believe.